# How to change value of global variable inside of promise Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code:

```
    query.equalTo('idColetor', arrayIdColetor[i]);
        query.greaterThan('tsmilliseconds', tsmillisecondsCurrent[i]);            
        var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('BusDroid', query); 

        promise.then(function(response) {
          if(response.length > 0){
             for(var j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {                 
                 path.push(new google.maps.LatLng({lat: response[j].lat, lng: response[j].lng}));                 
             }

             tsmillisecondsCurrent[i] = response[j - 1].tsmilliseconds;
    }
});
```

I declare the array tsmillisecondsCurrent as global variable `var tsmillisecondsCurrent = []`.
But when I change the tsmillisecondsCurrent value `tsmillisecondsCurrent[i] = response[j - 1].tsmilliseconds;` this value isn´t update out of this promise function.

What should I do to change value of global variable inside of promise?

Comment: That is because of the variable `i`. The scope of the variable `i` decides the update to your array `tsmillisecondsCurrent`. When the promise is executed the value of `i` would have changed.  How is `i` initialised?

Comment: above of this promise, I have: for(var i = 0; i < arrayIdColetor.length; i++){ the code described
}
Tku

Comment: You are accessing the global, the problem is what [debatanu mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33710687/227299). I like to explicitly use `window.globalVarName` to make it clear to readers that it's a global. Actually, I'd rather not have a global at all, but if you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a loop, the `i` variable changes by the time the promise is executed. You can try something like this

**EDIT**

```
var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('BusDroid', query); 
   /*create a custom index for promise object*/
   //promise.index=i; This wont work
    promise.then(
      (function(index){
       return function(response) {
      if(response.length > 0){
         for(var j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {                 
             path.push(new google.maps.LatLng({lat: response[j].lat, lng: response[j].lng}));                 
         }

         tsmillisecondsCurrent[index] = response[j - 1].tsmilliseconds;
        }
}
 }(i))//this will work, by passing i here it will retain the value
);
```